# Eclipse does not output

Tags: java, eclipse, static, output

I am new to Java and I can't seem to get Eclipse to output a float value. Any help is appreciated.

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Float> prices = new ArrayList<Float>();

        prices.add((float) 66.46);
        prices.add((float) 66.34);
        prices.add((float) 66.82);
        prices.add((float) 66.37);
        prices.add((float) 66.56);
        prices.add((float) 66.89);
        prices.add((float) 67.80);
        prices.add((float) 68.25);
        prices.add((float) 67.88);
        prices.add((float) 67.80);

        System.out.println(program(prices);
    }

    //there is a lot of code in between but I dont think it is needed here

    float program(ArrayList<Float> prices) {
        float prob = counters(prices);
        return prob;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the cause is. I suspect the issue if because I have nothing in the `public static void main(String[] args)` but when I call a function like `main()` or `program(prices)` in it, it requires me to change them to static.

Comment: You did not call any method from main, So how can you get output without calling from main method ? You should call you desired method from main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Java interpreter executes an application (by being invoked upon the application's controlling class), it starts by calling the class's main method. The main method then calls all the other methods required to run your application.

Now a typical definition of main method from which execution start is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

And in your code, you don't have anything in the actual `public static void main()` function. So, when you run your code, nothing is happening.

> So what you can do now?

You can do **any** of the following two things.

- Shift all your code from `void main()` to `public static void main(String[] args)`.
- Do something like this.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main obj = new Main();
    obj.main(); // this will call the void main() function
}
```

> When I call a function like `main()` or `program(prices)` in it, it requires me to change them to static.

Yes, you cannot call a non-static function like `main()` or `program(prices)` from a static function `public static void main()`.

So you can do **any** of the following two things.

- Make the method `main()` or `program(prices)` static. Ex., `static float program(ArrayList<Float> prices)`.
- Create a object of class Main and then call the methods as shown below.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your other code here
    Main obj = new Main();
    System.out.println(obj.program(prices);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete void main() and put that code in public static void main(String[] args).
Your main method has nothing in it thus it is returning null value.
Try:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Float> prices = new ArrayList<Float>();

    prices.add((float) 66.46);
    prices.add((float) 66.34);
    prices.add((float) 66.82);
    prices.add((float) 66.37);
    prices.add((float) 66.56);
    prices.add((float) 66.89);
    prices.add((float) 67.80);
    prices.add((float) 68.25);
    prices.add((float) 67.88);
    prices.add((float) 67.80);

    System.out.println(program(prices));


}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but i did it again and it showed me the same problem. There is a red line under program and it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method program(ArrayList<Float>) from the type Main" and it suggests changing program() to static.

Comment: Looks like you are not familier with method references:Go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

In static main method create new instance of you class, and then invoke a main method of that object without parameters. Other case, if it is just one class application, you may change your main method to static.

BTW, do not name your methods like "main", usually such method is meaning a "entry to the application".